# Is it possible to install Mac os x in virtual machine on a macbook pro?

Tags: install, virtualization, virtualbox

I'm going to try diffrent versions of MacOSX on my macbook pro. I have a Snow Leopard installed there, and need something else (possibly a Tiger) as second solution, to test the software.

So I thought of a virtual machine that would be running on my Snow Leo and have a Tiger running on it.

I tried VirtualBox, and install a MacOsX from there (from a .iso disk image), but it basically hangs during the very beginning of the instalation.

Is there any good and easy to perform solution to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only version of Mac OS X that can be legally virtualised is Mac OS X Server:

http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-macosxguests

Answer (score 2):

It is however possible to install a client version of OS X in e.g. VMware Fusion - but not out of the box.

First you need to re-pack the installation DVD with a small correction (addition of one empty system file), telling Fusion that it is a server edition you are installing - and after the installation you need to do the same change in the installed OS X - then you are up and running.